# EF6 entity with DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity Guid Id force insert my Id value

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first

I am trying to use EF to export/import the existing database of a DbContext. In this context, there are several entities with Guid Id properties with DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity defined by the ModelBuilder. When I re-import the entities, I want to use the Id value from the serialized object, but it always generates a new Id value when I save the changes. Is there any way to force EF to use my Id value in this case? I know DatabaseGeneratedOption.None will allow me to do it, but then I will always be responsible for generating the Id. I know there segmentation issues of the index that occur without using sequential Guids, so I do not want to do this.

Am I out of luck or has anyone found a trick?

Update: we have decided to simply change all Guid Id from DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity to DatabaseGenerationOption.None and provide the Id ourselves. Although this leads to index fragmentation, we do not expect this to be a problem with the smaller size of our tables.

Comment: If just exporting/importing things I'd not use EF.  is this SQL server?  Just export the table contents as scripts and re-import by running those scripts perhaps?  I can't think of any easy way that wouldn't require a special version of the code to be run for the import task - which I guess you're trying to avoid?  In effect you want the EF equivalent of `SET IDENTITY INSERT ON` but I don't think this'll work without also changing the entity model stuff, which may make EF think the DB needs upgrading...

Comment: Unfortunately it is a requirement that I use EF to do this because it would work with any database software (and not just SQL server, which we are using).

Comment: [This sounds awfully like you aren't attaching the object to the objectcontext and setting its state to modified (the default is add)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421370/efficient-way-of-updating-list-of-entities/11421706#11421706).

Comment: I was hopeful that this may be the easy solution. I get what I expected: it does an update in sql but there are no affected rows.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want by defining two contexts that derive from a base context. One context defines its keys with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`, the other one with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`. The first one will be your regular application's context.

This is possible by virtue of Guid primary keys not being real identity columns. They're just columns with a default constraint, so they can be inserted  *without* a value, or *with* a value without having to set `identity_insert` on.

To demonstrate that this works I used a very simple class:

```
public class Planet
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The base context:

```
public abstract class BaseContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly DatabaseGeneratedOption _databaseGeneratedOption;

    protected BaseContext(string conString, DatabaseGeneratedOption databaseGeneratedOption)
        : base(conString)
    {
        this._databaseGeneratedOption = databaseGeneratedOption;
    }

    public DbSet<Planet> Planets { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Planet>().HasKey(p => p.ID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Planet>().Property(p => p.ID)
                    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(this._databaseGeneratedOption);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

The context subclasses:

```
public class GenerateKeyContext : BaseContext
{
    public GenerateKeyContext(string conString)
        : base(conString, DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
    { }
}

public class InsertKeyContext : BaseContext
{
    public InsertKeyContext(string conString)
        : base(conString, DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)
    { }
}
```

I first run some code to create and seed the source database:

```
var db1 = @"Server=(localDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true;Database=GuidGen";
var db2 = @"Server=(localDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=true;Database=GuidInsert";

// Set initializers:
// 1. just for testing.
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<GenerateKeyContext>());
// 2. prevent model check.
Database.SetInitializer<InsertKeyContext>(null);

using (var context = new GenerateKeyContext(db1))
{
    var earth = new Planet { Name = "Earth", };
    var mars = new Planet { Name = "Mars", };
    context.Planets.Add(earth);
    context.Planets.Add(mars);

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And a target database:

```
using (var context = new GenerateKeyContext(db2))
{
    context.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

Finally this is the code that does the actual job:

```
var planets = new List<UserQuery.Planet>();
using (var context = new GenerateKeyContext(db1))
{
    planets = context.Planets.AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
using (var context = new InsertKeyContext(db2))
{
    context.Planets.AddRange(planets);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now in both databases you'll see two records with identical key values.

You might wonder: why can't I use one context class, and construct it either with or without the `Identity` option? That's because EF builds the EDM model only once for a context type and stores it in the AppDomain. So the option you use first would determine which model EF will use for your context class.

Comment: I was not able to use this because we need to do imports with the Guid Ids onto the same database schema that we are exporting from. When I tried to do this with the same database, it threw an exception saying that the database context has changed. So I would need to make a migration for the DatabaseGenerationOption.None context, which would then make it incompatible with the DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity context.

Comment: Yes, I lazily ignored that scenario, but with my modifications you should be OK.