# With EntityFramework, how can I make two databases with the same context but one without auto-increment IDs?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm using EntityFramework Code-First with a context that has a model like:

```
public class Person {
  public int ID {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

with a context like

```
public class DataContext: DbContext {
   public DbSet<Person> People {get;set;}
}
```

And this gets saved into DatabaseA. When I insert a new person, it auto-generates an ID for that person. I need to have a DatabaseB that has the exact same structure, but *without* the ID auto-generation. I want to transfer some records from DatabaseA to DatabaseB but without DatabaseB generating new IDs. I know that I can wrap

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

around the ID property, but I only want it to apply to DatabaseB without affecting DatabaseA.

So the only solution I've come up with so far is to have a new model

```
public class PersonB : Person {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public new int ID { get; set; }
}
```

and a new context

```
public class DataContextB : DbContext { 
     public DbSet<PersonB> People {get;set;}
}
```

But this is a bit of a nuisance, as I'd have to maintain two sets of fairly identical models. Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something in 
using(var db = new DataContextB) {
db.
}

Comment: make two context subclasses, one of which configures all keys as `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` by *fluent mapping*, not data annotations. A bit like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47231878/861716).

Comment: At most you would need a new Context, not a complete Model. You can specify the Identity stuff in `override OnModelCreating()`

Comment: You can use fluent api to make your ID not identical.

Comment: we use the two lines var option = Writeversion ? DatabaseGeneratedOption.None : DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity;
            modelBuilder.Types<BOBase>().Configure(x => x.Property(y => y.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(option));, where WriteVersion is a flag set in the constructor of the context. this allows the same context to have differing models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `OnModelCreating` function of DbContext and write some fluent api code.

Please have a look on this approach

```
public class DataContextB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People {get;set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(t => t.ID)
                    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: What's wrong with that?

Comment: Well, even though OP accepted the answer it doesn't tell how to make this optional. OP wants to work both with and without identity.